# In ruby, how can I order lines in an array by date?

Tags: ruby

In the following output, each line contains a date and it is unordered. How can I order each line by its date? Note, the list is in an array.

```
Wilkinson Stacy NYC 1/22/1964 Shocking Pink
Bednar Filomena New York City 1/24/1980 Salmon
Goyette Timmothy London 10/2/1964 Pacific Blue
Nolan Rhiannon LA 10/4/1974 Vivid Tangerine
Bruen Rigoberto SF 12/1/1962 Raw Umber
Parker Matteo Melbourne 2/14/1962 Burnt Sienna
Cummerata Elliot New York City 4/3/1947 Neon Carrot
Kirlin Mckayla Atlanta 5/29/1986 Maroon
Barrows Anika Hong Kong 5/5/1965 Spring Green
```

Comment: A hint for the future: You can add code fragments with 4 leading spaces.

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more? Are you trying to sort the lines by the date within?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? I and possibly others were still preparing answers and @BananaNeil was working on an edit. Moreover, had you only wanted to sort dates, there was no reason to embed them in strings. I'm no more please that you switched the greenie to my answer. The point is: there is no rush. Give it a couple of hours.

Comment: Good point Cary! Will do! Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = <<-BITTER_END.split("\n")
Wilkinson Stacy NYC 1/22/1964 Shocking Pink
Bednar Filomena New York City 1/24/1980 Salmon
Goyette Timmothy London 10/2/1964 Pacific Blue
Nolan Rhiannon LA 10/4/1974 Vivid Tangerine
Bruen Rigoberto SF 12/1/1962 Raw Umber
Parker Matteo Melbourne 2/14/1962 Burnt Sienna
Cummerata Elliot New York City 4/3/1947 Neon Carrot
Kirlin Mckayla Atlanta 5/29/1986 Maroon
Barrows Anika Hong Kong 5/5/1965 Spring Green
BITTER_END

require 'date'
arr.sort_by { |line| Date.strptime(line[/\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d{4}/], '%m/%d/%Y') }
  #=> ["Cummerata Elliot New York City 4/3/1947 Neon Carrot",
  #    "Parker Matteo Melbourne 2/14/1962 Burnt Sienna",
  #    "Bruen Rigoberto SF 12/1/1962 Raw Umber",
  #    "Wilkinson Stacy NYC 1/22/1964 Shocking Pink",
  #    "Goyette Timmothy London 10/2/1964 Pacific Blue",
  #    "Barrows Anika Hong Kong 5/5/1965 Spring Green",
  #    "Nolan Rhiannon LA 10/4/1974 Vivid Tangerine",
  #    "Bednar Filomena New York City 1/24/1980 Salmon",
  #    "Kirlin Mckayla Atlanta 5/29/1986 Maroon"]
```

As @xlembouras notes, tack on `.join("\n")` to return the array to a string, should that be desired.

Comment: I like the full ruby approach!
How about a `join("\n")` at the end to return the initial input format?

Comment: Cary, you've just reminded me of a number of little ruby tricks that I have not used in years. Love the `line[regex]` trick. +1

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do to it is to turn them all into date objects and then sort.

The biggest problem with these dates is that they are in US format, if they were formatted `day/month/year`, so you'll have to use `Date.strptime`

```
require 'date'

dates = ['1/22/1964' ,'1/24/1980' ,'10/2/1964' ,'10/4/1974' ,'12/1/1962' ,'2/14/1962' ,'4/3/1947' ,'5/29/1986' ,'5/5/1965']

dates = dates.collect {|date| Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")}.sort

#if you want them to go back to the same format
dates.collect {|date| date.strftime("%-m/%-d/%Y") }
```

## EDIT

It looks like you edited your question. If you are trying to sort the lines by the dates within, you'll want to use `sort_by`

if you have an array that looks like this:

```
array = [
  "Wilkinson Stacy NYC 1/22/1964 Shocking Pink",
  "Bednar Filomena New York City 1/24/1980 Salmon",
  "Goyette Timmothy London 10/2/1964 Pacific Blue",
  "Nolan Rhiannon LA 10/4/1974 Vivid Tangerine",
  "Bruen Rigoberto SF 12/1/1962 Raw Umber",
  "Parker Matteo Melbourne 2/14/1962 Burnt Sienna",
  "Cummerata Elliot New York City 4/3/1947 Neon Carrot",
  "Kirlin Mckayla Atlanta 5/29/1986 Maroon",
  "Barrows Anika Hong Kong 5/5/1965 Spring Green",
]
```

then you can sort those lines by the date by doing this:

```
array.sort_by do |line|
  date = line.match(/\d+\/\d+\/\d+/)[0]
  Date.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `dates` array like

```
dates = ['1/22/1964' ,'1/24/1980' ,'10/2/1964' ,'10/4/1974' ,'12/1/1962' ,'2/14/1962' ,'4/3/1947' ,'5/29/1986' ,'5/5/1965']
```

You can sort it using [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

```
require 'date'

dates = ['1/22/1964' ,'1/24/1980' ,'10/2/1964' ,'10/4/1974' ,'12/1/1962',
         '2/14/1962' ,'4/3/1947' ,'5/29/1986' ,'5/5/1965']

dates.sort_by { |x| Date.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y") }
#=> ["4/3/1947", "2/14/1962", "12/1/1962", "1/22/1964", "10/2/1964", "5/5/1965", "10/4/1974", "1/24/1980", "5/29/1986"]
```

without messing with the initial array at all.

If you want reverse order you can add a `.reverse` at the end.